# Finding optimal solution from discrete array

Tags: optimization, gekko, discrete

I wonder if we can limit variable range between a non-interger numbers , but discrete ones.
Let say I have an array of N=[[2.3 ,4.5, 5.8] , [6.4,7.1,4.1]] .
A is a variable array elment of N[0,i] for i<3, which means A = 2.3,4.5,5.8 .
B is a variable and = array elment of N[1,i] for i<3 which means B = 6.4,7.1,4.1 .
A,B are discrete by not integer.
I want to find max of c = a+ b .
so a = 4.5, b =7.1 .
I am looking forward to you response. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `A` and `B` are separate variables then use the `sos1()` function to define them as discrete, non-integer values.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
A = m.sos1([2.3,4.5,5.8])
B = m.sos1([6.4,7.1,4.1])
m.Maximize(A+B)
m.solve()
print(A.value,B.value)
```

If the index must be the same for both `A` and `B` (same column) then define `C` as an `sos1()` type.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO()
A = np.array([2.3,4.5,5.8])
B = np.array([6.4,7.1,4.1])
C = m.sos1(A+B)
m.Maximize(C)
m.solve()
print(C.value)
```

Here is more information on [Special Ordered Sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_ordered_set) the `sos1()` type in the [Gekko documentation](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html?highlight=sos1#logical-functions).

Comment: Thank you. The index must be the same for both A and B. However, is there a way to print out the answer of value of A and B from ur second code.

Comment: Something like this gets the index of the maximum: `print(np.argmax(A+B))`.